# change from 3.5 inch to full size app

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I am changing setting in Build Settings and when I run, my app is running as 3.5 inch screen (supposed to run as 4 inch app). I try to re-configure and it is not okay. What kind of things shall I check back so that app will run as full size screen?

Before I change, my app is running as full screen size on iphone 5. Now, it only run as 3.5 inch screen size.

Comment: Please post some code, screenshots, etc.

Comment: It is in build setting. I didn't change any code. I would like to run as full size iphone screen.

Comment: "It is not okay" does not establish a clear programming problem. How is it not okay?

Comment: I need to run as full size iphone screen instead of 3.5 inch screen. I didn't change any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have correct Default (Launch) Image Sizes for iPhone & iPad, please see this link for  [default image size for iphone/ipad](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/launchImages.html)